# How to filter JSON Array at source?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm creating an SPFx webpart and I'm showing some output in Nested accordions but I want to group my output by "WeekNO".

Below is my working snippet.

On ButtonClick

```
private getListItems(): void {
  if (typeof this.props.listName !== "undefined" && this.props.listName.length > 0) {
    sp.web.lists.getById(this.props.listName).items.select("Title", "ID", "ResourceEmail",  "WeekNo", "Resource/Title")
    .expand("Resource").orderBy("WeekNo", false).get()    
    .then((results: Array<any>) => {
    this.setState({ items: results });
    }
  }
}
```

The above code returns a JSON output in "results" variable.
I want the same JSON output GroupBy `WeekNo` key before assigning it to `this.setState`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method getItemsByCAMLQuery in pnp js.

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/

**Test Demo:**

```
public _getItems():void {
    var caml="<View><Query><GroupBy Collapse='True'><FieldRef Name='Title'/></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'/></OrderBy><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields></Query></View>";
    let web = new Web(this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
    web.lists.getByTitle('test').getItemsByCAMLQuery({ViewXml:caml}).then(response=>{
      response.forEach(element => {
        console.log("Title:"+element.Title +"----ID:"+element.ID)
      });

    });

  }
```

**Test Result:**

[image]